# MySQL Case Insensitive but Accent Sensitive UTF8 Unique Key

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, collation

I know there are a lot of similar questions on SF, but I think mine is different enough to warrant a new question. I have a table that has a single column as utf8 with utf8_unicode_ci. It also has a unique key on this column along with another column marking a language code. The data in the column is in many different scripts (Latin with various accents, Chinese, and Russian, among others).

The problem is that I will sometimes want to enter in two words with different meanings that only differ by a diacritic (i.e. Spanish ano vs año). Since utf8_unicode_ci is both case and accent insensitive, it thinks these are the same and will only let me enter one. That sucks. Ideally, I'd just switch the whole column over to some collation that's case INsensitive but accent sensitive, but that doesn't seem to exist. A lot of different stuff uses this column, so I'd rather not change the column's default collation to utf8_bin for fear of messing stuff up with case sensitivity.

So, all of that said, I need some solution that will not affect default case sensitivity in the many existing queries that hit this column, but will let me add in words that differ by only a diacritic. Ideas? I'll switch just the unique key constraint to utf8_bin if I have to, but I'd rather not as I never want two things in the table that differ only by case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of (without finding a collation that fits your needs) is to change something at the application layer (outside of MySQL) that will take care of the differentiation.

For instance, since you don't care about case, you can do something programmatically to lower the case of all the rows in the database. Then change the collation to utf8_bin.

Then you can, in the application, convert everything to lowercase before it enters the database (I'm guessing this will not affect the diacritic characters). That way, you will still get errors if people try to enter multiple cases, you should only have to change a few lines of code to precondition stuff entering the table, and you won't have the diacritic problem.

Comment: Some uppercase characters don't have a lowercase equivalent. Some have multiple lowercase equivalents. It's kind of a mess.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to reinvent the flat tire (reinvent the wheel) here.

There are two Spanish-language collations in MySQL:

utf8_spanish_ci  (modern Spanish) and
utf8_spanish2_ci (traditional Spanish)

These know the language well enough to know that N and n should be collated together, but that  Ñ and ñ are different letters between N and O. In Spanish, the Ñ is actually a different letter, not an accent.

Set your column collation to utf8_spanish_ci and all will work the way you want.

Comment: Thanks, but like I mentioned, it's not only Spanish I'm worried about. There's stuff in a bunch of different languages.

Comment: Hmm. The folks who dreamed up Unicode collations are excellent linguists. If there were a universal solution that did the right thing for all Roman-alphabet languages they would have implemented it.  You may need to do some language sensitive querying, based on your user's language.  You can place a COLLATE clause in a WHERE statement.