# mysql utf8 latin, fails on duplicate key entry

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have just received an SQL insert script, but it fails on a duplicate key entry:

I am trying to insert :

1)Montaña

2)Montana

My tables are all utf8_spanish2_ci,

can anybody explain why this is happening ?

Comment: Related: [MySQL Case Insensitive but Accent Sensitive UTF8 Unique Key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11005647)

Comment: Related (explaining why this happens): [MySQL diacritic insensitive search (spanish accents)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3304464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `utf8_spanish2_ci` [collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324900/i-dont-understand-collation-mysql-rdbms-character-sets) is indeed not only case insensitive, but also partly accent insensitive, so <strike>`ñ` = `n`.</strike> (as Joni Salonen points out, this is incorrect!) but `á` = `a`.

<strike>There is, as far as I know, no collation that does *not* come with this "feature" except `utf8_bin`.</strike>

What you can do:

- Use a binary collation for the table (this comes with [other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526334/what-effects-does-using-a-binary-collation-have), though)
- Use a binary collation for the specific *column* (possibly your best bet)
- Use a different column as the key column - are you sure that column needs to be a unique key in the first place? If this is for a primary key, wouldn't a numeric auto-increment be much better suited?

Comment: If the column containing "Montana" and "Montaña" is supposed to have unique rows, the dbms needs to know that. Doesn't matter whether you add a numeric column as a surrogate key. A numeric surrogate without a unique constraint on *this* column would allow rows like `{1, Montana}`, `{2, Montana}`, `{365, Montana}`, and so on.

Comment: @Catcall yeah, but I'm not sure whether that really is the true requirement. This could be a case of the OP wrongly picking the name as the primary key instead of an auto increment. We will see

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I ended up using varbinary as my column data type and utf8_spanish_ci as my character set ( since this is faster then ut8_bin ? ? ) 

I have an unique key on this column, my primary key is auto_increment

Comment: 1. utf8_spanish2_ci does consider ñ distinct from n. 2. utf8_bin is a lot simpler than utf8_spanish_ci; I doubt it can be slower.

Comment: @Joni oh, I stand corrected! Thanks. Then it's really weird why this happens. Although seeing as `à` = `a` even in the spanish collations, this might become a problem later anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the collation considering Montaña and Montana to be identical.

(The collation determines the result of String comparisions.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this particular column has the collation `utf8_spanish2_ci` ?

The words Montana and Montaña are NOT equal according to this collation, as you can verify with this SQL:

```
mysql> select 'Montana' = 'Montaña' collate utf8_spanish2_ci as eq;
+----+
| eq |
+----+
|  0 |
+----+
```

Is it possible that somehow the collation is changed to utf8_general_ci? In this collation n and ñ  are equal.