# mysql collation: case-preserving, case-insensitive but accent-sensitive

Tags: mysql, utf-8

well I know the question about accent sensivity with case-insensivity exists, but the best solution I found was making everything lower case in the application (before SQL even happens) which causes another problem: the fact of case preservation.

techically there are 2 "types" of case sensitivity to remind:

the "real" case-*sensitivity*, for search and similar things so JosÈ = josè (or not)

and the case-*preservation*: a non case preserving system automatically converts all characters into upper or lower case before using it (josè -> JOSÈ and JosÈ -> JOSÈ), as far as I can remember DOS does that for example.

In other words, it doesnt even "remember" the case, so technically a non-case-preserving system is also case insensitive (as it doesn't care about the case *at all*, **but** I want that the case is preserved so they can be greeted like "Hello Josè" but I can still search for "josè" in the database and get my result while "jose" doesnt return "Josè"

so a short summary (as it is advissed per guidelines)

- case preserving (it stores the actual case -> Josè)
- case insensitive (it doesnt care about it while searching -> Josè == josÈ)
- accent sensitive (accented letters matter -> Josè != Jose != José)

what is the best way to achieve this?

(before downvoting, rather give a comment and let me do it better)

Comment: I *think* the duplicate should help, and still has the correct answer (although I'm happy do be corrected). Let me know if your case-preservation requirement (which I'm not quite sure I completely get) does *not* make this a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: well German2_ci is (probably) contrained to German language, and latin1_ci is constrained to latin, but I wish to use unicode as I plan the application to be as global as possible. so latin/German will be a problem as soon as for example Japanese characters pop up...

what I was referring to is http://stackoverflow.com/a/11006684/4426048
there is suggested to convert all data to lower before it getting into SQL, but that way you dont know (preserve) the original case used to enter it so if registerung a "Josè". I wish to greet him with "Josè" and not "josè" just because everything was lowered

Comment: also in the marked question the answers try to search by the hex value or so case-sensitive which is far away since it should be insensitive
here's more about preservation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_preservation

Comment: Yeah, it's a problem with no ideal solution. The only thing that comes to mind is having a separate column with lowercase letters in an accent-sensitive collation, and doing your comparisons on that

Comment: If you want case folding, but accent sensitivity, please file a request at http://bugs.mysql.com .